# Crystal Reports and Visual Studio 2013 preview

Tags: crystal-reports, visual-studio-2013

I just installed VS2013 preview and the integration of Crystal Reports is not working. I installed "Crystal Reports for Visual Studio V13.0.6", this provides integration in VS2012.

Is there any hack/trick to integration CR into VS2013preview, so that I can edit reports?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As of 10/23/2013:

> Service Pack 7 for “SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio” does not support Visual Studio 2013. Service Pack 8, ETA first quarter 2014, is planned to support VS 2013 as well as WIN 8.1.

- [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio - Service Pack 7 - Fixed Issues](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/SAP+Crystal+Reports,+developer+version+for+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+-+Service+Pack+7+-+Fixed+Issues)
- [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio: Updates & Runtime Downloads](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Comment: Latest update from SAP site.
There is no  version of CR that will work with VS 2013 -...... Only option; wait for SP 9 - ETA, end of March.

Comment: they released the SP9 in April. 
Service Pack 9 for SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio does support VS 2013 and is now available for download. 

you can download it from here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Comment: visual studio 2013 update 5 not able to install crystel report tried days failed

Answer (score 12):

> Service Pack 9 for [SAP Crystal Reports, developer version for Microsoft Visual Studio](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)
>   is now available for download. Don't forget that to integrate CRVS
>    into VS IDE you must run the install exe(!).
>   And yes, CRVS SP 9 does support VS 2013. List of fixes and Supported
>   Platforms documentation coming next week.

Source: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3425566